# MySqldump Version Dismatch

Tags: mysql-workbench

Estoy intentando exportar una base de datos de `MySql WorkBrench` y me saca este mensaje. Si hago click en continuar, la hace con errores y no sale ningún archivo.

¿Cómo se puede solucionar? Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dice que debes actualizar la versión de _mysqldump_ en tu computador.

Comment: Si, intentente hacer lo que indica en el ultimo parrafo y no tuve exito. El archivo mysqldump no lo tomo bien tampoco; me seguia tirando el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Ahí indica que las versiones de tu servidor y tu cliente son distintas, tu server mysql es 10.4.8 y tu cliente es 8.0 de tu workbench y tu mysqldump es 8.0.15, deberías buscar clientes compatibles con tu servidor mysql, podrías instalar Adminer(https://www.adminer.org/) es un cliente para base de datos escrito en php, super ligero y funciona muy bien.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Cual de todos los Adminer deberia instalar para resolver esto?

Comment: Buenas Miguel Zarate, acaso esto "deberías buscar clientes compatibles con tu servidor mysql" no responde a la pregunta del por qué el error? si me quitaron los puntos por responder a una consulta mal planteada :/